# SQL Server - Add a linked server to AWS RDS instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, linked-server

From this AWS link it explains how to add a linked server:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Specifically these commands

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N’REPLTest2′, @srvproduct=N”, @provider=N’SQLNCLI’, @datasrc=N’repltest2.datacenter.mycompany.com′;
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N’REPLTest2′,@useself=N’False‘,@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'<username>’,@rmtpassword=‘<password>’;
```

The main problem is it seems to be a mix of ', `, and "

I get syntax errors, and I assume that's why. Plus, I don't know why it has the N before a bunch of them. It looks to me like they copy and pasted the commands, but the characters changed. I'm not sure how to fix these syntax errors.

I ran it as is without changing anything. I knew it would error because the connection variables weren't changed, but I wanted to see the syntax errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '’'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near '’'.
>
> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '’,@rmtpassword=‘’;
> '.

Comment: The `N` prefix before a string literal indicates that this is a **Unicode** string literal (to be stored in a `NVARCHAR` column). This is irrelevant in most Western languages, but absolutely essential if you're using Hebrew, Arabic, Cyrillic, or Asian languages and their alphabets

Comment: @marc_s I knew there was someone smarter on here than me that this would make sense to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, but want to leave the question in case others run into the same problem.  Below is the corrected syntax.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'REPLTest', @srvproduct='', @provider='SQLNCLI', @datasrc='IP-or-url';
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname='REPLTest',@useself='False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser='username',@rmtpassword='password';
```